# tableview reload data not working

Tags: uitableview, alamofire

Tableview not refreshing after an API call. And here is my code.And Im using dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell in cellforRowatIndexpath, Is there anything wrong with this?.

```
func getPreviousHistory() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let url = ServiceUrl.userOrder
        var previousOrderArray = [[:]]

        let params1: [String : String] = [
           "userid" : UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userid")!

        ]
        print(params1)

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params1).responseJSON()  {
            response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let data = response.result.value {

                    if (data as? [String : AnyObject]) != nil{

                        if let dictionaryArray = data as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                            previousOrderArray = dictionaryArray["data"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>

                            self.sortedOrdersDictionary = self.sortArrayDictDescending(dict: previousOrderArray as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>, dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")

                            DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("RESPONSE ERROR: \(error)")
                if let err = error as? URLError, err.code  == URLError.Code.notConnectedToInternet
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        popupConstants.sharedInstance.showAlert(title: "ALERT", message: "Please check your Internet connection",view: self)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        popupConstants.sharedInstance.showAlert(title: "ALERT", message: "An Error Occured",view: self)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check with either debug or print statements if the result enters in your specified conditional loops. Also could you show an example of the result of your Api.